# How to update name of List<Employee> during iteration in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I have List employeeList object and traversing resultset then adding employee detail in employeeList, If same employee is come during traversinng then need to append its roles with existing attribute.

```
while(rs.next()){
   ListIterator<Employee> itr = employeeList.listIterator();
   while (itr.hasNext()) {
     if(employeeList.getId() == rs.getLong("ID"))){
       // need to append roles in employee
     }
   }
}
```

I want to append role in employee if same employee in resultset.
e.g: employes Ram have 2 roles Admin and standard so 1st time it will set role using employee.setrole(rs.getString("RoleName")) but 2nd time I need to add the role in same employee. How can i do this.

Comment: If a user can have multiple roles, then roles property in Employee bean should be a list of strings, not a String.

Comment: Do you want to update the employee role or you want another role to be added for same employee. in case if you want to add another role than how do you want to store multiple role for employee. Do you want to use list of role or you want to append role in the existing role "String" ex : Admin, standard

Comment: Please share complete code..

Comment: If you wish to append the role like concatenation of String ... In if loop check for employee.getRole() != null than do append it by getting  "employee.getRole()" + current Role . Add any delimiter you wish too.

Comment: Don’t spam your question with tags, why spring and is it java 6 or 8?

Comment: @Varun In application its required to append role in the existing role.

Comment: @raviraja you are right but its not my requirement.

Comment: You should change your data structure. Searching for an ID by looping over a `List`, for every row of a `ResultSet` will result in horrible performance for larger data sets. That’s the typical kind of code that works fine in your test environment with a few records and fails at customers with real life data. You should use a `Map` from id to `Employee`. Or, if these `Employee` are database entities, don’t do this in Java code at all. In that case, let the database perform the update.

Comment: @Nitin What is wrong than you can simply get the employee object from list and then get the role of the employee and update the role as you want and then set it back the role of that employee, do let me know if you face any problem

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would use a Map rather than a list when going through the result set to look up employees on id before updating the role.

```
Map<Integer, Employee> empMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e));

while (rs.next) {
    Employee e = empMap.get(rs.getLong("ID"));
    if (e != null) {
        String role = rs.getString("RoleName");
        if (e.getRoleName() == null) {
             e.setRoleName(role));
        } else {
            e.setRoleName(e.getRole() + ", " + role);
        }
    }
}
```

If possible it's better to have the adding a role name functionality in a method in the Employee class

```
public void addRoleName(String role) {
    if (this.role == null) {
        this.role = role;
    } else {
        this.role +=  ", " + role;
    }
}
```

which simplifies the loop

```
while (rs.next) {
    Employee e = empMap.get(rs.getLong("ID"));
    if (e != null) {
        e.addRoleName(rs.getString("RoleName"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `while(rs.next()) empMap.computeIfPresent(rs.getLong("ID"), (k,e) -> { e.addRoleName( rs.getString("RoleName")); return e; });`